# Problems with merge replication

Tags: sql-server-2008, merge-replication

We are developing a multi-user desktop application with users located in different countries. The platform is - .net 3.5, SQL Server 2008, WinForms. Now, my client has used the help of a DBA who has implemented merge replication. To facilitate replication, we made all our primary keys as GUID. Now, we are facing these issues with replication -

subscribers expiration sometimes stops replication and we have found no clean way to re-add
every change to db schema requires to poll the whole data all over again! This seems to be strange, what could be the problem here?
Also, sometimes we have duplicate keys, and that too stops replication
I am sure these issues can be resolved. Maybe, we have not gone the right way to implement. Can you suggest how to go about implementing. Or, is the above information enough to diagnose the problem?

Answer (score 0):

DB Schema changes with Replication can frequently require the replication to be re-initialized.

The underlying causes of your other problems with Merge-Replication will require the DBA to figure them out.  I know this is the short answer, but there are too many ways for Replication to not work and any answer here is most likely wrong.